# Angular 4 - Routing issue , added a new route and it looks like others, but on page refresh it throws 404 error

Tags: angular, router, angular-routing, routerlink

On the terminal on my localhost i can see npm say  **" 404 error /coins"**

Then On the page it says  **Not Found**

These URLS work fine

```
 http://localhost:8808/events/new
 http://localhost:8808/events
```

But I ADDED in this "coins" one

Go there

```
http://localhost:8808/coins
```

Refresh is problem

navbar.component.html

```
    <li>
      <a [routerLink]="['/coins']">All Coins</a>
    </li>
    <li>
      <a [routerLink]="['/events']">All Events</a>
    </li>
    <li><a [routerLink]="['/events/new']">Create Event</a></li>
```

Then routes.ts

```
export const appRoutes:Routes = [
{ path: 'events/new', component: CreateEventComponent },  // process this first , since we have events/:id
{ path: 'events', component: EventsListComponent },
{ path: 'events/:id', component: EventDetailsComponent },
{ path: 'coins', component: CoinsListComponent },
{ path: '', redirectTo: '/events', pathMatch: 'full'}

]
```

index.html

```
 <base href="/">
```

So everything was working until adding this coins... and doing a page refresh , even a hard refresh.

1. This is not Angular 1  (angularJS )   this is 100%  the angular latest 4.0 version with the `import { Routes } from '@angular/router'`

**What could be the problem ?**

Update:   showing Coin component

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core'
import { CoinService } from './coin.service'

@Component({
    template: `
    <div *ngFor="let coin of coinsList">
     abc
     </div>
    `
})
export class CoinsListComponent implements OnInit {
    coinsList:any[]
    constructor(
        private coinService: CoinService
    ){
    }

    ngOnInit() {
        console.log('oninit coins')
        this.coinsList = this.coinService.getAllCoins()
    }
}
```

Comment: Is the server responding with the `index.html` when you make a request to `http://localhost:8808/coins`? If it does not then the angular app will not be loaded when you refresh the page on that route.

Comment: If i click on the Link on the page (spa   index.html)   i does go to url you said  .../coins and  console.log does show   `oninit coins`    which is correct as i have coins-list.componet.ts which has an  ngOnIit function with that console.log ...    It is when i then right click and refresh the page ...  page not found ...  so annoying

Comment: makes me wonder if this pluralsight angular fundamentals course with that  /events redirect is covering up the fact that perhaps  'events' would possibly "blow up" if there wasn't that last redirect ...   ughh

Comment: can you show your coin component?

Comment: this is weird. your code looks fine. The error should be somewhere else

Comment: showing coin component

Comment: it is super strange  , i cannot think /see what could be wrong   especially when a link is clicked on and it emits code from the component etc

Comment: So when you refresh the page on any other route, say `/events` it doesn't give 404 right?

Comment: So if i go to   /events    and hit refresh I see it briefly showing /events/   then i removes the  trailing "/"   ,  with  /coins , refresh instantly on refresh the URL stays  /coins and it displays the 404

Comment: @echonax    Correct  ,  as i typed comment same time as your comment  ,  the   /events goes to   /events/   then /events     i assume the  base on the index.html

Comment: What do you use in your back-end?

Comment: GET http://localhost:8808/coins 404 (Not Found)    ,   on refresh i see in  dev tools  console output  ,  but not if i click and navigate with the routerLink on the html nav page of the spa

Comment: so on windows,   latest version of  node/ npm  ...   i'm not using anything but the  npm start

Comment: what does your npm start do? what do you use to serve your app? node.js? azure? iis?

Comment: `"start": "tsc && concurrently \"npm run tsc:w\" \"npm run server\" ",`

Comment: and then also in package.json   `"server": "node node_modules/ng2f-server/server.js",`

Comment: So while i have used  web api /mvc for years,   i have used locally node ,  iissnode ,   liteserver and a few other lightweight little servers  -  once it is deployed i suppose i will end up under IIS   --  i just didn't expect this issue

Comment: If i change base href to   href="."   then Url for coins is then   `http://localhost:8808/events/coins`    not what i want,  but refresh works ...

Comment: Is your CoinsListComponent imported and declared in your Module?

Comment: @StephenR.Smith    yes

Comment: 404 is definitely coming from your server, most likely your server is not redirecting all the calls to `index.html`. If there is a 404, means Angular app hasn't started,

Comment: Trying making the href to be absolute path, and making sure your server configuration is correctly redirecting,

Comment: are you able to reproduce this issue if you using _ng serve_ and visiting _localhost:4200_ ?

Comment: you have to make sure that server routes are properly configured to make this work as you are not using `HashLocationStrategy`.

Comment: @micronyks   can you explain in an answer

Comment: what do you want to understand @JeremyMiller ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What are you using server side? ExpressJS? 
If so seems that you haven't setup something like

server/server.ts

```
const app: Application = express();

app.route('/api/coins/').get(coinsRoute);
```

server/coinsRoute.ts

```
export function coinRoute(req, res) {

res.status(200).json({ ...
   });
}
```

And you have a tab running the Express server as well as the app in another tab in your console.

Answer (score 0):

Use `useHash:true` withing `@NgModule` in `app.module.ts`

```
RouterModule.forRoot(appRoutes, { useHash: true })
```

Answer (score 0):

Keep your app running with a node server. I fixed with the following code.

//server.js

```js
Keep your app running with a node server. I fixed with the following code.

//server.js

   
    'use strict';
    
    var express = require('express');
    var app = express();
    var bodyParser = require('body-parser');
    var logger = require('morgan');
    var port = process.env.PORT || 8000;
    var path = require('path');
    
    
    var environment = process.env.NODE_ENV;
    
    app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: true }));
    app.use(bodyParser.json());
    app.use(logger('dev'));
    
    // var filespath = require("path").join(__dirname, "index.html");
    // console.log(filespath);
    
    switch (environment) {
      case 'build':
        console.log('environment')
        app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, "/")));
    
      // Any deep link calls should return index.html
      app.use('/*', express.static(path.join(__dirname, "index.html")));
        break;
      default:
        console.log('development');
        app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, "/")));
    
      // Any deep link calls should return index.html
      app.use('/*', express.static(path.join(__dirname, "index.html")));
        break;
    }
    
    
    app.listen(port, function() {
      console.log('Express server listening on port ' + port);
      console.log('env = ' + app.get('env') +
        '\n__dirname = ' + __dirname +
        '\nprocess.cwd = ' + process.cwd());
    });

for more you can see my code in git: https://github.com/HelloSofts/hoq-prod
```

for more you can see my code in git: https://github.com/HelloSofts/hoq-prod